# How to check a radio button in the table row based on that column header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario like below:

I have to add the attribute 'checked' on the radio button which having the header 'MyHeader2'

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      MyHeader
    </th>
    <th>
      MyHeader2
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' name='testradio' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' name='testradio1' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to implement this in jQuery?

Comment: you can make some good usages of `Array.prototype.findIndex()`

Comment: If you give the ditfferent names to those inputs, you will be able to select them both. Is that what you want?

Comment: My header is dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better consider using `data-attributes` where you need things like this.

Makes life easy for you.

Just add heading as data property to checkbox like

```
data-heading="MyHeader"
```

And then it'll be easy for you to select it like

```
$("input[data-heading='MyHeader2']")
```

```js
$("input[data-heading='MyHeader2']").prop("checked", true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      MyHeader
    </th>
    <th>
      MyHeader2
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' data-heading="MyHeader" name='testradio' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' data-heading="MyHeader2" name='testradio1' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("table tr th:contains(MyHeader2)").each(function(){
  var i = $(this).index(); //Get the index of the th.
  $("table tr td:eq("+i+") input:radio").prop("checked",true); // Set the radio to checked. 
})
```

**demo**

```js
$("table tr th:contains(MyHeader2)").each(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  $("table tr td:eq(" + i + ") input:radio").prop("checked", true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      MyHeader
    </th>
    <th>
      MyHeader2
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' name='testradio' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' name='testradio1' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the header index based on the value of header `MyHeader2`. Using this index you can select the radio button in the `td` and mark it checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var headerValue = 'MyHeader2';
  $('table tr th').each(function(index){
    if($(this).text().trim() === headerValue){
      headerIndex = index;
    }
  });
  $('table tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('td:eq('+headerIndex+')').find('input[type=radio]').prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
     MyHeader
    </th>
    <th>
      MyHeader2
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
       <input type='radio' name='testradio' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='radio' name='testradio1' />
      </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
       <input type='radio' name='testradio3' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='radio' name='testradio4' />
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```